# Catching escaped characters in C

Tags: c, unix, tr

My program deals with arrays and escaped characters. Essentially it models the `tr` Unix command. For the most part it works, except when dealing with escaped characters. When using the `tr` command, it goes something like this:

```
$ echo "abc" | tr "abc" "\nxy"

xy
$
```

However, the way I'm currently solving the problem for the same example above my program returns:

```
\nx
```

My program doesn't catch that this is an escaped character and treats it normally. But I can't figure out a way to solve this issue. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
size_t q;
int s,c;
unsigned char table[256];

for(s = 0; s < 256; s++)
{
   table[s] = s;
}
for(q = 0; set1[q] !='\0'; q++)
{  // Ensure if there are excess characters in set1,
   // they are replaced by the last character of set 2
   if(q>=length(set2))
   {
     table[(int)set1[q]] = set2[length(set2)-1];
   }
   else if(set2[q] != set1[q])
   {
      table[(int)set1[q]] = set2[q];
   }
}

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
   putchar(table[c]);
}
```

Comment: We can't fix code we don't see.

Comment: And how are we supposed to help without a [mcve] and mor details are detailed in [ask]?

Answer (score 1):

The strings you are working with are not the same strings as you are giving to `tr`

Here's your first string broken down into characters:

'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'

Here's your second string as characters:
   '\', 'n', 'x', 'y', '\0'

Here's the string that `tr` is seeing:

'\n', 'x', 'y', '\0'

So your code is doing "the right thing" with the strings it is given.  If you gave `tr` the second string you would get the same results as  your program produces.  In order to do this you would have to escape the backslash (using a backslash of course) so your program is equivalent to:

tr "abc" "\\nxy"

rather than:

tr "abc" "\nxy"

The solution is to honor the escape sequences in the second string before passing them to your code.  It would be a good idea to do this in a separate function because it is a useful tool to have and and your program will be cleaner if you concentrate on one task at a time.

You can write your own function to do that or you can look for a function written by someone else to do that.  (google is your friend)

Once you have code to do the conversion, if it doesn't work as expected come back and ask another question. [If it does work as expected, you win!]

RE: how to write it?  Iterate through the input string creating another string as you go.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I just looked into it, but it turns out my program treats "\\nxy" as if it were "\nxy" leading to no difference. They both still give me "\nx" just as before. Do you know what could be causing this? @Dale Wilson

Comment: @GreenSkies: You're fighting the shell.  Use single quotes if you want to know what your program is seeing.  With `"x\ny"` as an argument, your program is passed a 4-character string because `\n` doesn't have a special meaning in this context.  With `"x\\ny"`, the sequence ``\\`` does have a special meaning — it means a single backslash — so your command is again passed a 4-character string.  If you used single quotes instead, you'd be seeing a 4-character string for `'x\ny'` and a 5-character string for `'x\\ny'`.  Understanding when the shell is interfering is key.

Comment: The code should honour escape sequences in both the mapping strings.  If you're truly emulating `tr`, then you need to handle octal escapes `\007` (does that ring a bell?), and also ranges `a-z` etc.  That is, the current expansion loop in the question is not yet as sophisticated as it will need to be.

Comment: It's not a complete model of the tr command, the program I'm implementing only has to model certain features. Nevertheless, I'm looking into the issue.